# Google chrome remote desktop connection only display wallpaper

Tags: gnome, remote, google, openbox

I installed Google Chrome Remote Desktop without any problem, i can connect to the machine but for some strange reason all i get when i connect to the computer is the wallpaper and the mouse pointer i don't see the current desktop session in progress, and i was wondering if anybody could provide a solution to my problem? I have gnome and Open box desktop environment installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no solution, since there is no problem.
Chrome Remote Desktop (as a default behaviour) does not allow you to control the ongoing session.
Instead, it creates another virtual session on tty20, as explained [in the reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/8PMxG69VJ6o).

> By default, the system will create a virtual desktop that is 1600x1200 pixels in size.

It is something completely different from, say, Teamviewer, because it does not allow you to manipulate an open session.
Instead, it creates a new one.
The first time that I saw it I was surprised to, and I ended up uninstalling it ;)

Googling a bit I found that there is a workaround to modifiy this behaviour, [this](https://superuser.com/a/850359).
I just want to point out and stress that this is not the way it is intended to work, so it might end up breaking something.

Comment: its funny because on Windows it uses the current session and even displays it to the monitor for the world to see. i was surprised to get a new session on linux

Answer (score 2):

You definitely *can* control the active desktop session on Ubuntu 18.04 via Chrome Remote Desktop by simply following these instructions exactly. It works perfectly.

@MDMower's answer to [Super User: "Configuring Chrome Remote Desktop with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04"](https://superuser.com/a/850359/425838) [note: works perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04 as well!].

### Update 26 Apr. 2020

Actually, Chrome Remote Desktop on Linux has been super buggy and I haven never been able to get it to consistently work for any period of time longer than a few months over the last 3 years. See this answer here, for instance: [Automount when clicking on disks in GUI file manager suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu. ("Unable to mount...Not authorized to perform operation.")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in/1196273#1196273).

Therefore, I've switched to NoMachine and recommend you do too. It works *extremely well* and is virtually bug-free and very well-supported. See my link just above for more details.

Comment: Nice! I like that NoMachine just uses the GUI that you alread have instead of adding a new/different GUI interface like some of the other options out there.