# Unable to access location: Not authorized to perform operation

Tags: 18.04, mount, partitioning

In Ubuntu 18, this error is caused by Chrome Remote Desktop. The solution is:

Stop the Chrome Remote Desktop Service: (use terminal)

/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --stop
Open all external disks, that logo appears

Start again the Chrome remote desktop service:

/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start

I think you have to do this after each reboot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automount when clicking on disks in GUI file manager suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was related to chrome remote desktop app. I was logged in as another user. Once i logged out from remote app, i was able to acces the drives