# Failed to mount Volume. Not Authorized to perform operation

Tags: 18.04, mount, vnc, sd-card

I'm using an SBC (Khadas VIM1) with Ubuntu 18.04.6.
I have an SD card formatted in FAT32 on it and I'm having access to Ubuntu via the VNC server.

On the desktop, I clearly see that the SD card is correctly showing but when I try to mount it pops up the error *Failed to mount Volume. Not Authorized to perform operation*

[image]

I've read multiple questions about this issue like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199116/unable-to-access-external-hard-drive-not-authorized-to-perform-operation-u) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197600/unable-to-access-location-not-authorized-to-perform-operation)

The thing is that's no chrome remote desktop installed if I run `sudo apt autoremove chrome-remote-desktop` it says there no chrome-remote-desktop installed

If I manually mount it via terminal with `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1 /mnt/sdcard` everything works fine.

Could it be because the VNC server is running (that's strange to me as, even with the server running, I'm able to mount the sd-card via terminal)