# Unable to access USB flashdrive; not authorized to perform operation

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I got a notification that I cannot access my USB flash drive both 32GB and 64GB. Before it will auto-detect after being inserted. I am new to Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to explore more about it. I installed it alongside with Windows 10. I would greatly appreciate your help on this matter. Both flash drives were fine in Windows 10 if mounted.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have chrome-remote-desktop installed as a Chrome Extension there's a good chance that is the cause of problem.

See [Automount when clicking on disks in GUI file manager suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in) for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: List mount-able devices

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In my case I get:

[image: fdisk output]

Step 2: Create a directory to mount to

```
sudo mkdir /media/external
```

Step 3: Mount the drive now

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/external -o  uid=1000,gid=100,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

Replace `ntfs` with the `type`,  `/dev/sdc1` with the `device`

---

If that does not work , go to `/etc/inittab` and change default `runlevel` from `3` to `4`. With the next boot, your system will start GUI automatically, and those remaining options should be active.

Comment: Thanks, Bro for your help. Anyway, I figured it out lately as I learned from other member that chrome remote desktop may link your user account online and you are unable to mount your drive because other user has logged on. I deleted my profile out there after a while my usb drive has been detected. I logged out and reboot my desktop and mount the drive again and surprisingly my usb drive has been detected without hassle.

Comment: Glad that you solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this works for me,install USBGuard with synaptic.

Before the First Start
Prior to starting the USBGuard daemon (or service) for the first time (but after installation) we need to generate a rules file for USBGuard so that the currently attached USB devices (in particular mouse and keyboard) keep working so that you will not get locked out of your system.

A rules file can be generated like this:

$ sudo sh -c 'usbguard generate-policy > /etc/usbguard/rules.conf'
After that, you can safely start service usbguard:

$ sudo systemctl start usbguard.service
And you can make systemd start the service every time your boot your machine:

$ sudo systemctl enable usbguard.service